# Height of a table: what's the uncertainty?

Tags: kinematics, experimental-physics, error-analysis, free-fall

I would like to introduce high school students to error analysis with a simple experiment: find $g\pm \Delta g$ by measuring the time a ball takes to fall from a table, repeating many times.

Uncertainty of time of fall $\Delta t$ is determined statistically (standard error), since the measurements of $t$ must follow a normal distribution.

How about the height $h$ of the table, which is measured with a meter stick? $\Delta h$ is mainly due to the fact that the stick is never perfectly vertical during measurement, so the value read is necessarily greater than the true value. Thus it makes no sense to take $h$ to be the average of the values read, and since the measurements don't follow a normal distribution I don't know how to evaluate $\Delta h$ statistically. How would you find $h \pm\Delta h$?

Comment: "Δℎ is mainly due to the fact that the stick is never perfectly vertical during measurement" I wouldn't be so sure: the stick would have to be at 2.5° to the vertical to make a difference of 1 mm in the measured height of a tabletop 1 m from the ground.

Comment: Unless you have some more accurate way than a stopwatch—say, high frame rate video—to measure the fall time, any uncertainty in g due to height error will be negligible compared to the uncertainty due to time error. A more accurate way to estimate g is with a pendulum—for that method, the distance (length of the pendulum rather than height of table) would be a significant source of error.

Answer (score 1):

Uncertainties almost never have a unique cause. The vertical misalignment of the stick can be considered a systematic error, as a parallax error. In principle, it can be reduced below other sources of uncertainty by a careful experimental protocol or changing the way the height is measured. Still, I would expect some residual uncertainty, due to many other reasons (for example a not uniform height of the table or uncertainty in the reading of the length).

However, coming to your question, there is no difficulty in a direct evaluation of the spread around the average value, simply performing enough measurements to have a statistically meaningful sample of different values.

Comment: Your last paragraph may be correct, but in the case of measuring the height of the table some care is needed.   The actual measured distribution will not be Gaussian, in fact it has a hard stop at a minimum value.  You can measure an average and a standard deviation, but you can't compound uncertainties using the rules designed for normal distribution.   Better, I think:  instead of setting up the ruler and making the measurement, with little regard for the vertical angle,  intentionally vary the angle until the observer thinks they have gotten the minimum. That might be "more normal".

Comment: (continued from above) However, the uncertainty measured that way would be dominated by the precision of the ruler, not the variation in angle.   One might argue that the uncertainty due to small angular error should not be considered at all. as the length obtained has a second order dependence on angle.

Comment: @garyp as I wrote in my answer, the variation of the angle is a systematic error. One should try to get rid of it before discussing the statistics of the measured values.

Comment: Variation of the angle is a systematic error if there is something preventing the device from producing an accurate measurement.  Here that is not the case.  The ruler's  inclination can vary from perfectly vertical, to a little off to the left, a little off to the right, and so on.  A systematic error here would be things like the bottom two inches sawn off, incorrect spacing of the lines,  the bottom edge not perpendicular to the side if resting on the entire surface of the bottom under the assumption that it is perpendicular.

Answer (score 1):

In this case the experiment will be a good illustration not only of the uncertainty, but also of the [bias of an estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_of_an_estimator) - one could perform rather symple analysis for small angles. This however may be indeed  abit too much for your students.

A reliable way to introduce uncertainty is to use a chronometer that is started and stopped by humans - since human reaction time is some fraction of a second and noticeably varies from a persont to another. Time of a ball falling from a table is probably too short for this, but a ball falling from a building or rolling in a tilted pipe may be long enough for meaningful data.

Answer (score 1):

Let $H$ denote the random variable for the measurement of the height and $h$ a specific value for $H$.  Take a set of $n$ measurements for $H$: $h_1, h_2, ...h_n$.  I suggest using a variety of "rulers" to measure height to compensate for bias inaccuracies in the rulers themselves.  Estimate the mean of $H$ , $\mu_H = {{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}h_i} \over n}  $.  Estimate the standard deviation for $H$ as $\sigma_H  = \sqrt{ {\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{(h_i - \mu_h)^2} \over {n - 1}}}$.  Estimate the standard deviation *of the mean* of $H$ as $\sigma_{\mu H} = \sqrt{ {\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{(h_i - \mu_h)^2} \over {n(n - 1)}}}$.  The result is $\mu_H \pm \sigma_{\mu H}$ (what you call $h \pm \Delta h$).  Similarly, you collect data for the measured time $T$ and report the result as $\mu _T \pm \sigma_{\mu T}$ where $\mu_T$ is the mean and $\sigma_{\mu T}$ is the standard deviation of the mean.  I suggest using a relatively large height so the relative error in the ruler measurement is lessened, and so the error associated with starting and stopping the timer (especially if manual) is of less importance.

Let $G$ be the random variable for the measured gravity. $G$ is a function of $H$ and $T$: $G = {2H \over T^2}$.  The mean of $G$, $\mu_G = {2\mu_H \over \mu_T^2}$. You estimate the standard deviation of the mean of $G$ using a Taylor series expansion of the function $G = {2H \over T^2}$ about its mean. You can assume $H$ and $T$ are independent to evaluate the result for $\sigma_{\mu G}$, the standard deviation of the mean of $G$.  Your result is   $\mu_G \pm \sigma_{\mu G}$. The details for the series expansion can be found in standard tests for error propagation such as Data Analysis for Scientists and Engineers by Meyer, or online.

Answer (score 0):

I think that one should show that the error on the height of the table, between many measurements is **considerably smaller** than the error on the time of fall, which, of course, should be done **first**, to have an order of magnitude of $\Delta t/t$

Then one should measure $\Delta h/h$ for many measurements, find that it is **much smaller** and explain to the students that it is **useless and counterproductive** to look for details of a much smaller error. Any value of $h$ within the very small spread would do, except perhaps extreme ones, which would be obvious experimental errors, considering the much larger value of $\Delta t/t$.

This, I think, is the proper approach to error analysis. Insisting on details for $\Delta h/h$ would confuse your students. Indeed $\Delta h/h$ is probably smaller than the error on $\Delta t/t$ depending on whether you keep **all** the experimental values of $t$ or eliminate those too far away from the mean, which are obvious experimental errors.